# Flask: how to store and retrieve a value bound to the request

Tags: flask

I want to store a value that is bound to a Flask request, 
I want the value to live only as long at the request and it
should be availablbe in @app.after_request, 
how would the get_my_request_var and set_my_request_var be implemented
in the code below ?

```
@app.route("/aRoute")
def a_function():
    set_my_request_var('aName', request, 123)


@app.after_request
def per_request_callbacks(response):

    v = get_my_request_var('aName', request)

    return response
```

Comment: Depending on what you are using this for, it might be better to use a k/v store like memcache or redis.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'd set a value on the [`flask.g` globals object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.g) and retrieve that in the `after_request` handler:

```
def set_my_request_var(name, value):
    if 'my_request_var' not in g:
        g.my_request_var = {}
    g.my_request_var[name] = value


@app.after_request
def per_request_callbacks(response):
    values = g.get('my_request_var', {})
    v = values.pop('aName')

    return response


@app.route("/aRoute")
def a_function():
    set_my_request_var('aName', 123)
```

The `values.pop()` removes the key from the `my_request_var` dictionary on the global `flask.g` context, so that a future request won't have to handle it.

The global `flask.g` context is thread safe and tied to the current request; quoting from the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/appcontext/#locality-of-the-context):

> The application context is created and destroyed as necessary. **It never moves between threads and it will not be shared between requests.**

Another option is to not handle this in a `after_request` handler. Use the newer [`@flask.after_this_request()` decorator](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#flask.after_this_request) instead to register a callback for *just* this request:

```
from flask import after_this_request


@app.route("/aRoute")
def a_function():
    aName = 123

    @after_this_request
    def this_request_callback(response)
        # do something with `aName` here
        return response
```

or, in a helper function:

```
def something_after_this_request(aName):
    @after_this_request
    def this_request_callback(response)
        # do something with `aName` here
        return response            


@app.route("/aRoute")
def a_function():
    something_after_this_request(123)
```

Comment: two questions : 1) is global *g* shared between requests, 2) what happens if values.pop() never gets called (exception is thrown), will the var stay forever

Comment: `g` won't be usable in my case, since I want to guarantee that every request gets a cleared slot. A decorator is also not usable in my case since I will be setting the value depending on a dynamic condition. Thanks for answering though !

Comment: @MaxL.: actually, I was wrong. `g` *is cleared* between requests, it appears.

Comment: @MaxL.: sorry for the confusion there. Updated to confirm that `g` contains per-request data only.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer !